# Where does Heroku store compiled handlebars.js templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ember.js, asset-pipeline, handlebars.js

I've upgraded the [handlebars-source](http://rubygems.org/gems/handlebars-source) in my Rails/Ember.js app to 1.3.0 and am getting the following error after deploying to my Heroku staging environment.

> Template was precompiled with an older version of Handlebars than the
>   current runtime. Please update your precompiler to a newer version (>=
>   1.0.0) or downgrade your runtime to an older version (== 1.0.0-rc.3).

It seems like I should be able to delete these templates and recompile with the newer version of handlebars, but cannot figure out how. I have tried `rake tmp:clear` and `rake assets:clobber` on the Heroku server and redeploying, but it's still giving the same error.

Are these templates stored somewhere else where I can delete and have Heroku recompile them?

Other related gem versions:

- ember-rails (0.14.1)
- ember-source (1.5.0.beta.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still curious if there's a better way to do this, but the only way I could get it working was by changing the asset version number in config/production.rb file and redeploying:

```
# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
config.assets.version = '2.0'
```